# Pull two independent (content dependent) strings from a text

Tags: excel, string, search, excel-formula, vlookup

I have several thousand file name in column c. I have successfully been able to pull 1 string of specific text from the file names. I am hoping to pull more than one string from the text and concatenate the two as an output in a separate cell.

Example Filename: LexTEX-Summary-160kand90k

What I want to output is the 2-3 numbers before every "K" and concatenate them as an output in column T. In this case the output would be "160k/90k".

There are several scenarios I'm hoping to cover:

--1 "K" in file name (could be 3 or 2 #'s before). output: ##k where ## could be 2 or 3 numbers

--2 k's in file name (could be 3 or 2 #'s before both).output: "##k/##k" where ## could be 2 or 3 numbers

--no k found, ouput "Not found"

I want to just pull the numbers before any "k" found in the file name independent on how many there are. If this is not possible then I would just want to pull the 3 values before any "k" and concatenate all k's. The issue is that if the filename has a k in the name that is not associated with a number it is not relevant info My current formula only finds one of the two K's as seen below:

```
 `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),MID(E26,SEARCH({"k"}-{3},E26),{4})),"Not Found")`
```

Comment: Do you always have the `-` in front of the numbers and also the `and` between numbers?  And how many `-` will be in the string to parse?  Just want to know more about the pattern of the string.

Comment: I updated my question. the k's and the format surrounding the k's will vary. If there is a k in the filename proceeded by numbers, I want to extract that k with the numbers proceeding it (max amount of numbers proceeding the k will be 3). The number of k's, the number of numbers proceeding each k and the placement of each k in the string will vary

Answer (score -1):

If first k will always have 3 numbers preceding and second 2, you can use this formula.

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(C1,SEARCH("K",C1,1)-3,4),"/",MID(C1,SEARCH("K",C1,SEARCH("K",C1)+2)-2,3))
```

[image]

Comment: As a note, this formula is length dependent and may give incorrect results if the numbers are not exactly 3 characters and 2 characters respectively

Comment: I already mentioned that in answer, but thank you for additional emphasizing.

Comment: This is a good start but there are several scenarios I'm hoping to cover:
--1 k in file name (could be 3 or 2 #'s before). 
--2 k's in file name (could be 3 or 2 #'s before both).
--no k found, ouput "Not found" ........
I want to just pull the numbers before any "k" found in the file name independent on how many there are. If this is not possible then I would just want to pull the 3 values before any "k" and concatenate all k's. The issue is that if the filename has a k in the name that is not associated with a number it is not relevant info